# PCIEX-8000-KP error in sun solaris OS on HP BL servers

Tags: solaris, hp-proliant

Pls help me to resolve this problem in  HP BL 660c server,It is installed with Sun solaris 11 and showing errors fmadm faulty.its coming again while it repaired with the command
 fmadm repair UUID.

## fmadm faulty

---

TIME            EVENT-ID                              MSG-ID         SEVERITY

---

Dec 30 00:22:01 0cc05440-0275-60dc-8a7c-d254a508aa2f  PCIEX-8000-KP  Major

Host        : atnxadm2
Platform    : ProLiant-BL660c-Gen8      Chassis_id  : CZJ51008ZR
Product_sn  :

Fault class : fault.io.pciex.device-interr-corr max 8%
              fault.io.pciex.bus-linkerr-corr max 4%
Affects     : dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,7
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,1
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,2
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,3
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,4
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,5
              dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2/pci103c,1798@0,6
                  faulted but still in service
FRU         : "MB" (hc://:product-id=ProLiant-BL660c-Gen8:server-id=atnxadm2:chassis-id=CZJ51008ZR/motherboard=0) max 8%
                  faulty

Description : Too many recovered bus errors have been detected, which indicates
              a problem with the specified bus or with the specified
              transmitting device. This may degrade into an unrecoverable
              fault.
              Refer to http://sun.com/msg/PCIEX-8000-KP for more information.

Response    : One or more device instances may be disabled

Impact      : Loss of services provided by the device instances associated with
              this fault

Action      : If a plug-in card is involved check for badly-seated cards or
              bent pins. Otherwise schedule a repair procedure to replace the
              affected device.  Use fmadm faulty to identify the device or
              contact Sun for support.

---

TIME            EVENT-ID                              MSG-ID         SEVERITY

---

Dec 30 00:21:42 7a9aaf63-9fdf-6f7b-932f-db5f227d6a67  PCIEX-8000-J5  Major

Host        : atnxadm2
Platform    : ProLiant-BL660c-Gen8      Chassis_id  : CZJ51008ZR
Product_sn  :

Fault class : fault.io.pciex.device-interr-corr
Affects     : dev:////pci@12,0/pci8086,e06@2,2
                  faulted but still in service
FRU         : "MB" (hc://:product-id=ProLiant-BL660c-Gen8:server-id=atnxadm2:chassis-id=CZJ51008ZR/motherboard=0)
                  faulty

Description : Too many recovered internal errors have been detected within the
              specified PCIEX device. This may degrade into a non-recoverable
              fault.
              Refer to http://sun.com/msg/PCIEX-8000-J5 for more information.

Response    : One or more device instances may be disabled

Impact      : Loss of services provided by the device instances associated with
              this fault

Action      : Schedule a repair procedure to replace the affected device. Use
              fmadm faulty to identify the device or contact Sun for support.

Answer (score 0):

This recommended action is [from OpenSolaris source code](http://illumos.org/msg/PCIEX-8000-KP), (which does assume the error hasn't changed since Oracle bought Sun and ceased supporting OpenSolaris):

> If a plug-in card is involved check for badly-seated cards or bent
>   pins. Otherwise schedule a repair procedure to replace the affected
>   device. Use fmadm faulty to identify the device or contact Sun for
>   support.

Shut down, and inspect the PCI card(s), making sure every card is properly seated.  PCI ID `103c` is an ID used by HP, so the card is likely an HP card that's having issues.

Comment: We have sorted out this problem,detecting that one of the NIC card did these problems.We removed this card from mother board there is no error s stating PCI bus.